# Disable button on form submission but post button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to prevent multiple form submissions, but I need to have the value of the submit element posted back to the server (so that I know which button the user clicked on).

Most of the Internet Wisdom concerning suppression of multiple form submissions seems to involve disabling the submit button during form submission.  This prevents the button from being clicked a second time, but also prevents its value from being posted.

I've found a few examples of JS code that hides the submit button(s), which allows their values to be posted.  But those examples all replace the (now hidden) button with some sort of "processing..." message.  I really want a solution that presents the user with a disabled button but still posts the button value.

I should add that I'd prefer a solution that works with standard HTML one would find in most forms.  No magic IFrames, hidden fields, id or class names, etc.  I want a JS function I can stash away in a library and reference from all of my existing forms to enable this new behavior.

(I have a solution, which I will post as an answer.  But I had to ask the question to comply with the Zen of SO.)

Comment: can you create a demo of your code using http://jsfiddle.net and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to know which **submit** button was clicked in the first place? Usually you only have a single submit button per form to begin with. For example, do you have multiple _actions_ that take the same parameters and simply don't want to set-up several identical forms?

Comment: I usually have at least two buttons: "Ok" and "Cancel".  Sometimes I might also have something like a "< Back" button to move to the logically previous page (while retaining the info the user entered on the current page).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is (yet another) answer to the question of how to deal with preventing the user from clicking on the form submission button more than once.  This solution makes it appear that the button has been disabled.

Under the covers, it creates a disabled button to display to the user, and hides the actual button so that its value is posted.  I also move the hidden button so that the extra element doesn't mess up CSS selectors.

Also note the check for invalid form fields.  If you omit this check, and form validation fails, then the user winds up with a form that wasn't posted (because client-side validation failed) but the buttons are disabled.

```
// Disables buttons when form is submitted
$('form').submit(function () {
    // Bail out if the form contains validation errors
    if ($.validator && !$(this).valid()) return;

    var form = $(this);
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"]').each(function (index) {
        // Create a disabled clone of the submit button
        $(this).clone(false).removeAttr('id').prop('disabled', true).insertBefore($(this));

        // Hide the actual submit button and move it to the beginning of the form
        $(this).hide();
        form.prepend($(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you can submit a form other ways than simply clicking the submit button it's better to add a listener to the form's submit event rather than the click event on the submit button. This jQuery event listener should work on any form and prevent it from being submitted more than once.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).data('submitted')) {
        $(this).data('submitted', true);
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

To make the form look disabled you could add some css that makes the form look disabled and then add the classname on form submission.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).data('submitted')) {
        $(this).data('submitted', true).addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to stop the user from causing multiple form submissions by double clicking the submit button or hitting the enter key twice. I like this solution, because it doesn't require a hidden form field or hiding the submit button.

The two key points are:

1. Return true/false instead of using e.preventDefault() and form.submit(), because form.submit() doesn't know which button was clicked and therefore, can't pass the button name/value.
2. Disable the button with `pointer-events: none;` instead of   `disabled="disabled"`, because the disabled attribute won't send the button name/value. I believe `pointer-events: none;` is not supported by Internet Explorer 10 or below.

javascript/jquery code:

```
var form_selector = 'form',
    button_selector = 'button, input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset]',
    deactivated_classname = 'state-submitting',
    deactivated_class = '.'+'state-submitting';

// Capture the submit event so it will handle both the 
// enter key and clicking the submit button.
$(document).on('submit', form_selector, function(e) {
  var form = e.target,
      buttons = $( form ).find( button_selector );

  // Returns, because the form is already being submitted by a previous attempt.
  if( $( form ).find( deactivated_class ).length > 0  ) return false;

  disableButtons( buttons );

  // Safari (version 11) bugfix: Safari needs a timeout or it won't 
  // show the deactivated styles.
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Must use return true, because using form.submit(), won't pass the button value.
    return true;
  }, 50 );
});

function disableButtons( buttons ) {
  // Disables all buttons in the form.
  $( buttons ).each(function( index, elem ) {
    $( elem ).addClass( deactivated_classname );
  });
}
```

For AJAX forms, you will want to re-enable the buttons after the response is returned.

```
$( document ).on( 'ajax:complete', form_selector, function(e) {
  var form = e.target,
      buttons = $( form ).find( button_selector );

  enableButtons( buttons );
});

function enableButtons( buttons ) {
  $( buttons ).each(function( index, elem ) {
    $( elem ).removeClass( deactivated_classname );
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
// The button is disabled while it is submitting.
.state-submitting {   
  // Turns off hover and click events. Not supported in IE 10 and below.
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Well done on this "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5;" it is just brilliant clean and works great.
My solution to this is:
     $ ('form').submit (function (event) {
         if ($ (this).valid ()) {
             $(':submit', this).css({'pointer-events':'none', 'opacity': '0.5'});
         }
         return true;
     });

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate disabled look behavior. E.g. if you have a button like this:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" onclick="disableMe(this)" value="Submit" />
```

You can define CSS like this

```
.disabled {
    backround-color:grey;
    color:darkgrey;
}
```

And JS like this

```
function disableMe(btn) {
    btn.className = "disabled";
    btn.onclick = function(){return false}
}
```

What will happen - on first click button will become grey (via applied CSS) and onclick event will change to "return false" for all the consecutive calls preventing future click actions. The button will appear and act as disabled, but will not be, so it will not prevent button submission.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple options:

 1. You could create hidden inputs and dynamically change the value of it before the form is submitted either onClick or onHover of the said button: 

 2. You could create an hidden iframe which is the target of the said form. Once the submit button is click, you could cancel the submit event, grab all of the data and send it programatically through the iframe instead.

Comment: Re: #1, I guess I should have explicitly stated in the OP that I want a solution that doesn't involve extra (hidden) form fields or magic id or class values.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as OP, and I found that disabling the submit button(s) after a short (maybe 0 seconds) timeout via `setTimeout` does the trick. The submit button's name value is still posted with the rest of the form data as desired, but the button disables itself (almost) immediately, preventing further clicks.

The timeout is a bit ugly, but it seems preferable to more elaborate swapping/covering schemes.

This could be combined with also altering the form's `onsubmit` property for extra precaution, but I'm not doing that in the example below for clarity's sake. Either way, I like the appearance/behavior of a disabled button after the first submission click… the user experience seems better to me… it's more clear what's happening.

My form element's start tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" method="post" action="">
```

In my JavaScript (sorry, I'm not up-to-date with the latest JS tech like jQuery, etc, so I'm posting this in old-fashioned-native-JavaScript-5-with-no-dependencies-compatible code):

```
function formSubmit(form) {
    // MUST DELAY so as not to break input/button[type=submit] name submission
    setTimeout(function () {
        var els = form.elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            var el = els[i];
            if (el.getAttribute('type') == 'submit') {
                el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    }, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution would be to use JQuery :

```
<form onsubmit="$('#submit').hide();" method="post" action="">
```

No chance of double clicking.
Sometimes we use name field in submit button for validation so if this is disabled then that could failed.
Using .hide() the button will be hidden.
so no chance of double clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

Be honest with you I was not able to understand fully most of the posts on this page, but I think I have faced this problem before, and solved it by allowing the page to post the first time the button is clicked, so when the page comes back from server it has the new value assigned to it, and it looks clickable, and enabled. But if a 2nd attempt is made to press it, then it becomes disabled, and page will not post, and send to the server again by clicking this button. I hope this helps:

```
@section scripts
{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#edit').click(function () {
      if (document.getElementById("edit").value == '') { 
        // This portion should execute onlythe 
        // first time button is clicked, and it 
        // will assign a new value to the button, 
        //and posts the value 
        //to the server
      }
      else {  
        edit.disabled = true; 
      }
    });
  </script>               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much much much simpler way is to enclose whatever code you use to disable the button in a `setTimeout()` with 0 delay. That way the button is still enabled in the thread that handles the form submission while another parallel thread is spawned to do the disabling.

Example (using jQuery):

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="javascript:setTimeout(() => $('*[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'), 0)">
```